How can I convert HTML template file to PDF using jsPDF?
I have created already some jQuery code to make it work and it does but not exactly how it supposed to? Exactly I'm generating an invoice with HTML template that replace content and saving it as new html file. Then with jQuery on button click it should convert that generated invoice to PDF as A4 format. It does convert and downloading but when I previewing it has not properly size (does not fit content from HTML invoice).
This is code I have currently:
$('#convertToPdf').click(function(){
        var invoiceUrl = $('#invoiceLink').attr('href');
    
        $.ajax({
            url: invoiceUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(htmlContent) {

                var doc = new jsPDF();

                doc.html(htmlContent, {
                    callback: function (doc) {
                        doc.save('invoice.pdf');
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error('Error fetching HTML content:', error);
            }
        });
    });

I haven't tried anything yet without any ideas. I'm expecting generated invoice to fit in PDF (A4) format.



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Invoice Generator</title>
  <style>
    #invoice-container {
      width: 210mm;
      /* A4 width */
      height: 297mm;
      /* A4 height */
      padding: 20mm;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="invoice-container">
    <h1>Invoice</h1>
    <p>This is a sample invoice template.</p>
  </div>
  <button id="convertToPdf">Convert to PDF</button>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('convertToPdf').addEventListener('click', function() {
      const invoiceContainer = document.getElementById('invoice-container');

      html2canvas(invoiceContainer, {
        scale: 2, // Adjust scale for better resolution
        useCORS: true // Helps in loading images from external domains, if any
      }).then(canvas => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
        const pdf = new jsPDF({
          orientation: 'p',
          unit: 'mm',
          format: 'a4'
        });

        const imgWidth = 210; // A4 width in mm
        const imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;

        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        pdf.save('invoice.pdf');
      }).catch(err => {
        console.error('Error while generating PDF', err);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>



we get cores-origin exception for accessing file directly using the file:// protocol in the browser.
to resolve this use http-server and node.js
npm install -g http-server
http-server

This will serve your files at http://localhost:8080 by default.
